# pipe bash output to two different streams

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a bashscript that spawns processes on two different machines over ssh and then cat's the output of one into a text file.  How can I have the output ALSO displayed in the terminal as it's running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the `tee` utility (`man tee`).

Comment: And to do this with `tee` you issue the simplest possible command `cat output|tee filename`

Comment: Don't forget about standard error:    cat output 2>&1 | tee filename

Comment: what?...  Could you explain that line a little?  I'm a bit of a hacker when it comes to bash :-p

Comment: The first line `cat output | tee filename` will only capture regular output. If your program uses standard error for errors, you will see those on the screen, but they will not go to the file unless you add `2>&1` just before the pipe which tells the shell to redirect all standard error to standard output.

Answer (score 4):

The `tee` command is great when you want to save a stream to a file and continue processing it.  However, if you want to send stdout to two separate programs, you can use a while read loop and echo the output to stdout and stderr and then stream stdout to one program and stderr to another.

```
echo input | 
  while read foo; do
    echo "$foo"
    echo "$foo" >&2
  done 2> >( command1 1>&2 ) | command2
```

Here is a demo where the string "input" is prepended with a number to show where the outputs are going, and then sent as input to two perl programs that simply prepend the stream name.

```
echo input | 
  while read foo; do
    echo "1: $foo"
    echo "2: $foo" >&2
  done 2> >( perl -wpe 's//STDERR: /;' 1>&2) | perl -wpe 's//STDOUT: /;'
```

output is

```
STDERR: 2: input
STDOUT: 1: input
```

Caveat - the while/read/echo thing may not preserve line endings and binary text, and long lines will cause problems.  As with many things, bash may not be the best solution.  Here is a perl solution for anything but really huge files:

```
echo input | 
  perl -wne 'print STDERR; print;' 2> >( command1 >&2) | command2
```